# How Can I Calculate Hours between In and Out in specific Date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the hours between an in and an out date. The example table below holds both in the same structure. The first row on a date holds the IN and the second the OUT Time.

```
Emp_No  Stamp_Date  Stamp_Time

815     2015-02-03  1900-01-01 15:22:00.000
815     2015-02-03  1900-01-01 07:12:00.000
815     2015-02-04  1900-01-01 07:12:00.000
815     2015-02-04  1900-01-01 15:24:00.000
815     2015-02-06  1900-01-01 07:05:00.000
815     2015-02-06  1900-01-01 15:17:00.000
815     2015-02-07  1900-01-01 15:27:00.000
815     2015-02-07  1900-01-01 07:05:00.000
815     2015-02-08  1900-01-01 07:03:00.000
```

Comment: You should provide more information. How do you define the in and out in your table? Why do you use a datetime field and only populate hours in it? To much disc space or just to much money? :D

Comment: :))) thanks for reply..for ex: Case In : Time  should be between 07:00 and 08:00 AM .... Case Out : Time  should be between 14:00 and 16:00 PM...........because stamp clock data exported as excel

Comment: Yes but how do you determine which row is an in and which is an out? You just have timpestamps? Where is the logic behind it?

Comment: just group by Date ..i have In and out stamp type for ech time..but i have problem..too many emplyees just stamp no matter what status of check in and out..so i have to depend on period of 2 time in same day

Comment: Thanks for the background information. You should add it to the question itself to clarify what you mean instead of providing just the demo rows. I've added a answer which should do the thing you would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE #stamps (Emp_No int, Stamp_Date date, Stamp_Time time)

INSERT INTO #stamps(Emp_No, Stamp_Date, Stamp_Time)
VALUES  (815,N'2015-02-03',N'1900-01-01 15:22:00.000'),
        (815,N'2015-02-03',N'1900-01-01 07:12:00.000'),
        (815,N'2015-02-04',N'1900-01-01 07:12:00.000'),
        (815,N'2015-02-04',N'1900-01-01 15:24:00.000'),
        (815,N'2015-02-06',N'1900-01-01 07:05:00.000'),
        (815,N'2015-02-06',N'1900-01-01 15:17:00.000'),
        (815,N'2015-02-07',N'1900-01-01 15:27:00.000'),
        (815,N'2015-02-07',N'1900-01-01 07:05:00.000'),
        (815,N'2015-02-08',N'1900-01-01 07:03:00.000')

-- your Part
SELECT  pvt.emp_no, pvt.stamp_date, pvt.[1] as InTime, pvt.[2] as OutTime, 
        DATEDIFF(HOUR,pvt.[1], pvt.[2]) as differenceInHours
FROM (
    SELECT s.Emp_No, s.Stamp_Date, s.Stamp_Time, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.emp_no, s.stamp_date ORDER BY s.stamp_time) as inOut
    FROM #stamps s
) as dat
PIVOT(
    MAX(dat.stamp_time)
    FOR inOut IN([1],[2])
) as pvt

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #stamps
```

I'm using pivot to make some columns out of the rows. `[1]` is the time you go in and `[2]` is the time you go out.

Afterwards just use datediff to calculate the difference.

Due to the fact, that there is no information given, what to do if there is no out-Time for a record I just assume that it should be null and the difference is null too. You can use an `isnull` if needed.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaank you so much man..it work to me :)))..god bless you

Comment: another question .. how can i select * into new_Tbl from output Result....thank you

Comment: Hi, I don't get your question? What do you want exactly. By the way, it would be better to post it as a different question to hold the comments clean. :-)

Comment: i cannot post question ..after 6 day i can :)..that stackflow issue because i have negative point on posting question.

Comment: Well anyway, what do you want? :-) You can just add an `INTO ...` between the `SELECT` and the `FROM (` part

Comment: my question is related to this post .. when i have result from #stamps and using povit  >> the output result i need to inserted into another table using select into >> many thanks to you

Comment: yesss it works :)))) thankkkks with all respect and love

Comment: No problem. Have a nice weekend.